# How do I display the color channel of an image in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a XYZ tiled map. What should I do in order to make it display only 1 channel of color (for example only the red one or the green one) ?

Answer (score 3):

See ol.source.Raster, for example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/examples/color-manipulation.html

Comment: worth pointing out that the code required to only show one channel would be _far_ simpler than that in this example

Comment: Definitely, but it should get him/ her started.

Comment: Yup, just didn't want the OP to feel too daunted by that example

Comment: I tried simply changing my source code to : http://paste.isomorphis.me/tez yet it gives me the error on the bottom, any clue why?